# How to call the Nightwatch.runTests correctly?

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

When I call the Nightwatch.runTests method from the code, I get an error:

```
/ Connecting to 127.0.0.1 on port 4444...
    POST  /wd/hub/session - ECONNREFUSED
‼ Error connecting to 127.0.0.1 on port 4444.
_________________________________________________

   Error: An error occurred while retrieving a new session: "Connection refused to 127.0.0.1:4444". If the Webdriver/Selenium service is managed by Nightwatch, check if "start_process" is set to "true".    
       at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:407:9)
       at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:84:8)
       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

The documentation [here](https://nightwatchjs.org/guide/running-tests/#programmatic-api) and [here](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch-docs/blob/master/guide/running-tests/programmatic-api.md) says that the method accepts two parameters: [testSource] and [settings].
As [testSource] I specify the path to the folder with the tests. For [settings], I specify a json object equivalent to the contents of the nightwatch.json file. As stated in the error, the parameter "start_process" is set to true.

Here is the code to reproduce:

```
const Nightwatch = require('nightwatch');
const seleniumServer = require('selenium-server-standalone-jar');
const chromedriver = require('chromedriver');

const settings = {
    src_folders: ['tests'],
    output_folder: 'reports',
    detailed_output: true,
    live_output: true,
    selenium: {
        start_process: false,
        "server_path": seleniumServer.path,
        "log_path": "logs",
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 4444,
        "cli_args": {
            "trustAllSSLCertificates": true,
            "webdriver.chrome.driver": chromedriver.path
        }
    },
    test_settings: {
        default: {
            silent: true,
            disable_error_log: false,
            screenshots: {
                enabled: false,
                path: 'screenshots',
                on_failure: true
            },
        },
        chrome: {
            desiredCapabilities: {
                browserName: 'chrome',
                javascriptEnabled: true,
                acceptSslCerts: true,
                chromeOptions: {
                    w3c: false
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

Nightwatch.runTests('tests', settings).then(function() {
    // Tests finished
}).catch(function(err) {
    // An error occurred
});
```

In my project I use "nightwatch": "^ 1.3.6" and "selenium-server-standalone-jar": "^ 3.141.59".

I also changed the settings object, in accordance with the structure of the auto-generated file "nightwatch.conf.js":

```
const settings = {
    src_folders: ['tests'],
    output_folder: 'reports',
    detailed_output: true,
    live_output: true,

    test_settings: {
        default: {
            disable_error_log: false,
            launch_url: 'https://nightwatchjs.org',

            screenshots: {
                enabled: false,
                path: 'screens',
                on_failure: true
            },

            desiredCapabilities: {
                browserName: 'chrome'
            },

            webdriver: {
                start_process: true,
                server_path: chromedriver.path
            }
        },

        chrome: {
            desiredCapabilities: {
                browserName: 'chrome',
                chromeOptions: {
                    args: []
                }
            },

            webdriver: {
                start_process: true,
                port: 9515,
                server_path: chromedriver.path,
                cli_args: []
            }
        },

        selenium: {
            selenium: {
                start_process: true,
                port: 4444,
                server_path: seleniumServer.path,
                cli_args: {
                    'webdriver.chrome.driver': chromedriver.path
                }
            }
        },

        'selenium.chrome': {
            extends: 'selenium',
            desiredCapabilities: {
                browserName: 'chrome',
                chromeOptions: {
                    w3c: true
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

but this did not help, the error continues to arise.

I would be grateful if anyone could help solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `start_process: false` you need to set **`start_process: true`**,
and instead of `w3c: false` you need to set **`w3c: true`** effectively:

```
const settings = {
    src_folders: ['tests'],
    output_folder: 'reports',
    detailed_output: true,
    live_output: true,
    selenium: {
        start_process: true,
        .
        .
        "cli_args": {
            "trustAllSSLCertificates": true,
            "webdriver.chrome.driver": chromedriver.path
        }
```

and

```
chrome: {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true,
        chromeOptions: {
            w3c: true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This flag does not seem to affect the appearance of the error. After setting to true, an error also appears.

Comment: @xserjeo Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: I have made changes to my code in accordance with your recommendations. An error also occurs.

The next step, I changed the settings object, in accordance with the structure of the auto-generated file "nightwatch.conf.js".

But this did not help, the error continues to occur.